# Loading a type at run time using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to load a type at run time using reflection. Below are the steps:

1. Load the assembly using `Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);`
2. Use the `GetType` method to obtain the type
3. Use `Activator.CreateInstance` to create the instance of type.

Below is my code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName);
Type type = assembly.GetType("RomanConerter.Converter");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Problem I am facing is with the last line. My Converter has one method name `Add`. But I cannot access this method using obj.

Note: The assembly which I am trying to load in in other project, and I have hasrd coded the path.

Can anyone help me out please ?

Comment: Are you sure it's `RomanConerter` and not `RomanConverter`?

Comment: Actually its a custom converter, just a spelling mistake while creating the project will change that later

Comment: @ThiefMaster, something tells me that's just a typo...who knows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all depends on whether the type `RomanConverter.Converter` is available to you in your calling application (i.e. that contains the code you've posted).  If so, then you just cast.

If not - then you can late-bind the method with reflection (as others have said) or use `dynamic`, but imho you'd do better to use a common base or interface:

```
/* common interface used in both your code and the external DLL */
public interface ICanAdd {
  object Add(object source);
}
```

(I'm guessing the signature here)

And then change this plug-in type of yours to:

```
namespace RomanConverter {
  public class Converter : ICanAdd {
    object Add(object source){
      //TODO: implement
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you get the object from `Activator.CreateInstance` you just cast to `ICanAdd`:

```
ICanAdd obj = (ICanAdd)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Now you can call the method.

Comment: I wonder if this would work - the assembly is being loaded with LoadFile, which puts the types in it within a different load context - not sure if that means that any referenced types would not be castable.

Comment: whilst that assembly is in a different load context - I do believe that any assemblies it references are not, because they are subject to the normal assembly loading rules

Comment: @AndrasZoltan It is still not working I am not able to still access the Add method with above code.

Comment: @Jash - You have to store the result of the `CreateInstance` call in an `ICanAdd` - not an `object`.  So `ICanAdd obj = (ICanAdd)Activator.CreateInstance(type);`  I thought this was clear, sorry, have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

*dynamic* this:

```
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this. I used the dynamic binding and then I call the Add method. Like below
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
obj.Add -> But this add method is not accessible. I cannot see any interlisense hint for this Add method.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices: `dynamic` or huge amounts of reflection.

Try this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName);
Type type = assembly.GetType("RomanConerter.Converter");
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

obj.Add("stuff");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use reflection, you can use it as follows:

```
Type objType = obj.GetType();
objType.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
    null, obj, new object[] { /*comma-separated arguments here*/ });
```

You can read about it here: [`Type.InvokeMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx)

Comment: This also worked but i liked the stuff which @Andras Zoltan said.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast explicity to a type, that you are creating:

```
RomanConerter.Converter obj = (RomanConerter.Converter)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: Ain't gonna work. The type is not available at compile time. And what's that funny string-based cast? That's not C#.

Comment: I cannot do that. As the assembly name which i am loading comes at run time. So i am not sure which assembly will be loaded.It depends on Use input

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this can be done a few ways.

1. Implement an interface in your custom type, and have the interface available at compile time.
2. Use the `dynamic` keyword, as this will provide late binding to the object in question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use dynamic (or are using an earlier version of C#), you can use some reflection - which isn't too complicated for a simple method call:

```
obj.GetType().GetMethod("MethodName", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(obj, null);
```